# Sum-free sets in finite groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, additive-combinatorics, sumset

> Suppose $G$ is a group, $S \subset G$. Let’s call $S$ *sum-free* iff $\forall a, b \in S$ we have $ab \notin S$. Do there exist such $\epsilon > 0$, such that every sufficiently large finite group $G$ has a sum-free subset of cardinality $\geq \epsilon|G|$?

It was proved by Erdos using a very neat probabilistic approach, that for cyclic $G$ it is sufficient to take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{9}$. However I do not know what happens here in the case when the group is non-cyclic.

Comment: Do you mean to say "sufficiently large" at some point? I do not believe that it is correct that one may take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{3}$ for *every* cyclic group. Indeed, I believe $\mathbb{Z}_7$ has no sum-free sets of size larger than 2.

Comment: @KevinHalasz, it seems, that $\frac{1}{3}$ was also a typo. It should have been $\frac{1}{9}$. I accidentally wrote $3$ instead of $9$ because the actual fact proved by Erdos was a bit stronger than this. It was: "For any sufficiently large $n$ and a $A \subset C_n$ satisfying $|A| \leq \frac{n}{3}$ there exists a sum-free subset $B \subset A$ such that $|B|  \geq \frac{|A|}{3}$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no -- this was shown in Gowers' paper ["Quasirandom Groups"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3877).

From the abstract:

> Babai and Sós have asked whether there exists a constant $c>0$ such that every finite group $G$ has a product-free subset of size at least $c|G|$: that is, a subset $X$ that does not contain three elements $x$, $y$ and $z$ with $xy=z$. In this paper we show that the answer is no.

Specifically, it is shown that

> for sufficiently large $q$, the group $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q)$ has no product-free subset of size $Cn^{8/9}$, where $n$ is the order of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q)$.

(taken from page 2.)